# DOM-modification in Safari Extension

Tags: javascript, dom, safari-extension

I try to code a Safari Extension which visualizes some data on a website with tables. So, to compute the data I do a little JavaScript:

```
var table;
table = document.body.getElementsByClassName('summary');
console.log(table);

var rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
console.log(rows);
```

The second row works fine, but for the fifth row I get this error:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'table.getElementsByTagName('tr')')

Why is that? Whith this code:

```
document.body.getElementsByClassName('summary').getElementsByTagName('tr');
```

it's the same.

Whats my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` this method return you array so you need to pick table from this array:
`var rows = table[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');` if first found table is what you need but it seems that no tables are found in second line.

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much! I realize that Iam not yet so good in JavaScript. :-)

Comment: Minor correction: The result of getElementsByClassName is not a real array but a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/NodeList), which is an array-like object. Don't try to use array methods like pop and forEach on a NodeList.